# Bitcoin Full Node + Lightning running on single-board-computer, possible?

Tags: lightning-network, full-node

I know similar questions (regarding a Bitcoin Full Node) were already asked here, but they date all back to 2014 and I think especially the space needed by the blockchain changed a lot since then.

I am thinking of buying a single-board-computer to turn it into 24/7 online bitcoin full node + a lightning node. I want a single-board-computer to reduce the energy consumption, since it is running 24/7. My question is now what single-board-computer I should buy and how well that works. I read a lot about Raspberry Pi 3 and that its not working very well so I think of buying something more powerful.

At the moment I am thinking of a Banana Pi M3 or an ODROID-XU4.

Did someone already try something like this with another single-board-computer than the Raspberry Pi 3?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at pine64.org. They have the Rock64, which has a quad-core A53 ARM 64-bit CPU; up to 4GB RAM. And I have heard they will release a new model with a hex-core CPU soon as well. I have used the Pine64 (original 2GB model) for simple Linux experimentation; installed Ubuntu on it, etc. Have not tried Rock64 yet, but am planning to.

The ODROID XU4 may work well too, although I have found with my VPS full nodes, that 4GB of RAM is helpful... see: http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G143452239825

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-your-own-portable-plug-in-lightning-node-c4093a4b10fb is a good article on adding a pluggable LN node, it's not an "all in one", but IMO would be better to separate out the LN server.